# How do I calculate the factorial of a number in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, for-loop, syntax, factorial

Alright, so I asked an earlier question on my syntax error. I got rid of the errors, but the program doesn't do what it was intended to do. My math is wrong and doesn't find the number of trailing zeros. Here is my code:

```
num = " "
a = 0
sumOfFact = 1

def factorial
    num = gets.to_i
    a = num
    (1..num).each do |a|
        if a != 1
            sumOfFact *= a
            a -= 1
        else
            break
        end
    end
end

for c in 1..sumOfFact
    if sumOfFact / c == 10
            zeros += 1
    end
end

factorial()
puts sumOfFact
puts zeros
```

Comment: I see some variables, a method definition, a for loop, a method call and some puts. I'm a bit confused: what's the context of all this code? How is it supposed to interact? And what's the output that you've got so far?

Comment: Yup. There's no such thing as a 'continuation' in Stack Overflow. Please document your question properly since it needs to be understandable as a stand-alone item.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first, you should do the gets outside your method. Your method should accept a param. Second, why do you need the condition?

You want the multiplication from 1 to n to get the factorial. You should get started with this:

```
def factorial(n)
  total = 1
  (1..n).each do |n|
    total *= n   
  end
  total
end

puts factorial(gets.to_i)
```

Next is factorial with inject in case you want to learn new syntax :-)

```
def factorial(n)
  n == 0? 1 : (1..n).inject(1) { |total, i| total*= i; total }
end

puts factorial(gets.to_i)
```

As @pjs commented below, here's a beautiful way of doing factorial!

```
def factorial(n)
  n == 0? 1 : (1..n).inject(:*)
end
```

And, a final enhancement:

```
def factorial(n)
  (1..n).inject(1, :*)
end
```

Comment: OP don't have minimal understanding of the Ruby,, you are giving him `#inject`... lollz :)

Comment: What does inject mean? I don't want to use it if I can't understand it.

Comment: @user3251611 Please don't use `#inject`..for now.. :)

Comment: even cleaner would be `n.zero? ? 1 : (1..n).inject(:*)`, as long as you're using `inject`...

Comment: btw @pjs, beautiful solution!

Comment: Stuff like that is why I so enjoy using Ruby.

Comment: Very beautiful language :-) Did you see the last enhancement?`(1..n).inject(1, :*)` simply beautiful!

Comment: Actually, that one makes it incorrect because it now yields 1 rather than `nil` for negative values.

Comment: I would throw an exception but I'm not ready to get him into that haha =)

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that `n` is a non-negative integer number, you can define a method to calculate the factorial:

```
def factorial(n)
  tot = 1
  (1..n).each do |n|
    tot *= x
  end

  tot
end
```

Examples of its usage:

```
puts factorial(0) # 1 
puts factorial(1) # 1
puts factorial(2) # 2 
puts factorial(3) # 6
puts factorial(4) # 24
puts factorial(5) # 120
```

If you wan't to read the user input, call it like this:

```
puts 'Type the non-negative integer:'
n = gets.to_i
puts factorial(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Factorial
   attr_reader :num
   def initialize(num)
      @num = num
   end

   def find_factorial
      (1..num).inject(:*) || 1
   end
end

number = Factorial.new(8).find_factorial
puts number
```

Or you could just simply write:

```
 (1..num).inject(:*) || 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this too. Hope this helps anyone having the same problem in some way.

Method for finding the factorial of any number:

```
def factorial(number)
    for i in 1...number do
        number *= i
    end
    number
end

puts factorial(5)
```

Comment: could you pls explain?

Comment: Everything after the first sentence seems to be code. Code should be formatted by marking it in the editor and pressing Crtl+K. As it is now it is difficult to read.

Comment: looks better. Thanks. I'll try to be clearer next time :)